# Finding Average of Every "X" Amount of Rows

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the average of each player's score for each day. An example is as follows:

```
Date Player    RPE Score   Post Score
---  -------   ---------   ----------
8/26 Player 1      3           5
8/26 Player 2      4           6
8/26 Player 3      7           6
8/26 Player 4      2           9
8/27 Player 1      4           5
8/27 Player 2      -           -
8/27 Player 3      8           3
8/27 Player 4      1           2
8/28 Player 1      5           1
8/28 Player 2      4           9
8/28 Player 3      -           - 
8/28 Player 4      0           4
```

Using Excel, I'd like to have it so I can easily calculate each player's average RPE and Post score's (which is every 4 rows), so it would look something like this:

```
Player    RPE Score   Post Score
-------   ---------   ----------
Player 1      4           3.67 (11/3)
Player 2      4           7.5  (15/2)
Player 3      7.5         4.5  (9/2)
Player 4      1           5
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: either use a pivot table or AVERAGEIFS()

Comment: @ScottCraner would that be something like this: =AVERAGEIFS(C:C, B:B, "B = Player 1") ? That equation isn't returning a value, but it appears correct to me, for trying to find the avg RPE value in column C

Comment: Close: `=AVERAGEIFS(D:D,A:A,"Ash")` or `=AVERAGEIFS(C:C, B:B, "Player 1")` (depending on which columns you want to average)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks. However that gives me a dividing by zero error, which I'm not sure why since I would never be dividing by zero

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad whoops sorry that was just a typo on my end, that works great - thanks so much!